# Why don't my generated instances update when I change their prefab?

Tags: unity, c#, instancing

I’m making an Editor tool -- a ScriptableWizard -- that instantiates a prefab on a grid. But I find that when I update the prefab, the instances don’t update.

When I instantiate prefabs interactively in the Editor by dragging them from the Project panel to the Scene or Hierarchy, then updates to the prefab affect the instances as expected.

I see another difference between my scripted instances and the ones created when I drag the prefab into the scene: when I do it interactively, the instance in the hierarchy is listed in blue. But the instances I create from script using the same prefab are listed in black, similar to objects created directly in the scene.

Here’s the hierarchy; the “JitterPrefab” was dragged into the scene, and the ones under “gridParent” were instances of the JitterPrefab generated from my script:

[image: dragged vs generated instances in scene]

Here’s how I’m generating the instances:

```
public GameObject prefab; ...

void OnWizardCreate() { ...
  Transform instance = Instantiate (prefab.transform, pos, rot, parent.transform);
  instance.name = string.Format ("L{0:D2}-R{1:D2}-C{2:D2}", l, r, c);
  ... 
}
```

When I make a change on the prefab, e.g. change the radius of the Jitter script from 0.025 to 0.25, the manually created instance updates:

[image: change prefab...] [image: ...dragged instance updates]

But the script-generated instances do not:

[image: ...scripted instances don't update]

What am I doing wrong? Why are my scripted instances no longer connected to the original prefab?
And, separately, how to I tell in the editor (or in script) whether an object in the scene is an instance of a prefab or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instantiate creates it as a game object thus loosing the prefab link. You want to use [PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab.html)
in order to spawn the object in the scene and maintain the prefab link.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It sure would be nice if the docs on Instantiate (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html or https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html or https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) mentioned PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab() -- not a hint! Thanks for the tip, just what I was looking for!